# Constructor function. Can't overwrite reference to global variable

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I use this constructor to make objects for a game.
Right now, the series of images gets overwritten everytime, such that all the objects look the same on screen.

Here's the object in question:

```
function Box() {
    this.ready = false;
    this.pics = pictures;//[];
    this.state = 0;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.w = 1;
    this.h = 1;
    this.fill = "#444";
    this.load = function(array){
        var foo = [];
        pictures = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            pictures.push(loadPic(array[i]));
            foo.push(loadPic(array[i]));
        }
        //this.pics = pictures;
        this.pics = foo;
    }
}
```

The line

```
this.pics = foo;
```

seems to do nothing at all.

Also, if I change the initial value of pics to anything but "pictures" (which is a global variable) the game does not start.

Contex: https://github.com/kaninepete/Javascript-Games/blob/images/MVP.js

Comment: Do you ever call `box.load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you are creating your `player` and `target` objects and load their pictures by calling `load`. Because you are using the object-dot-method syntax, for example `player.load` to call the functions all references to `this` should be set as required/expected.

However to start the game, you are calling `reset` (for example from `myDown`). Within `reset` the objects in `player` and `target` are replaced with new instances (notice the calls to `addRect`). The method `load` is never called on the new instances and thus both are left with the identical pictures (the global `pictures` as initially set in `Box`). Because both are sharing the same array, `pictures`, they end up being painted the same.

General advice: I suggest to get rid of the global variables because their dependencies on each other are not obvious. Then you should call the `reset` function for initialization instead of doubling the implementation on the global level. Try painting a static picture first before introducing event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $this = this;
this.load = function(array){
    //...
    $this.pics = foo;
}
```

You must be aware that `this` inside a function is not the same `this` as in the constructor. In fact the one in `load()` function points to browser `window` object.

Instead we define a variable named `$this` (most people prefer `that` in pattern) and reference it from inside the function, making it a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `this` within a seperate function doesn't point to the object where the variable belongs.